# Aurelia observer not firing for array

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom data grid element simplified like this:

```
export class DataGrid {

  @bindable data;

  dataChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("Sensing new data...", newValue);
  }
}
```

It's instantiated like this:

```
<data-grid data.bind="records"></data-grid>
```

*"Sensing new data..."* and the array of records is displayed in the console when the data grid appears.  However, when I delete a record from the array of objects, the `dataChanged()` function is not triggered.

```
let index = this.records.findIndex((r) => { return r.acc_id === this.record.acc_id; });
if (index > -1) {
  console.log("Deleting element..." + index, this.records);
  this.records.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I get *"Deleting element..."* in the console but not *"Sensing new data..."*.

Any ideas why `dataChanged()` is not firing when I splice out a record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not observe an Array for mutations like that. You have to use a `collectionObserver` instead. Right now, your `dataChanged()` would only fire if you overwrite the `data` value (ie `data = [1, 2, 3]` which overwrites it with a new array).

---

Example how to use the `collectionObserver` from the `BindingEngine` class, for your usecase:

```
import { BindingEngine } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class DataGrid {
  static inject = [BindingEngine];

  @bindable data;

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this._bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  attached() {
    this._dataObserveSubscription = this._bindingEngine
      .collectionObserver(this.data)
      .subscribe(splices => this.dataArrayChanged(splices));
  }

  detached() {
    // clean up this observer when the associated view is removed
    this._dataObserveSubscription.dispose();
  }


  dataArrayChanged(splices) {
    console.log('Array mutated', splices);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is correct but haven't been able to get it to work yet.  I already have `static inject = [Element];`.  Can I make it `static inject = [Element, BindingEngine]; constructor(element, bindingEngine) { ... }`?  Or is that the source of my problem?  Is there an `@inject` decorator equivalent for `[Element]`?

Comment: They're equal. You can do either `static inject = [Element, BindingEngine];` or `@inject(Element, BindingEngine)`, but definitely not both. Both together would not work, so use either the `@inject()` or `static inject = [];` And then in the constructor: `constructor(element, bindingEngine)`.

Comment: That's what I thought.  But... still not working.  No error messages... and `dataArrayChanged()` is not getting triggered.  How can I debug?

Comment: Got it solved.  Because I was reassigning the whole array in the parent binding, the collectionObserver subscription was getting wiped out.  It works to keep the previous `dataChanged` and set up the subscription within there.

Comment: Oh okay. It's pretty weird to do both though (both mutate and reassign). :) Glad it worked.

Comment: Reassign when I get the list of records from the API, and mutate locally when I delete a record (without the need to refresh all the data from the API).

Comment: Ah okay. Makes sense I guess. I think I would personally run diffs on the datasets to make it more consistent, but it does not really make a difference (except consistency; performance wise nothing changes when the datasets are small). :)

Comment: Just a comment, while you shouldn't do both `static inject = [Foo]` and `@inject(Foo)`, you probably could do both. It's just that the decorator likely will win. https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/blob/master/src/injection.js#L36 You just can't do both `staic inject() { return [Foo]; }` because there is a check against that.. Now that I think about it maybe, that's a tiny bug :-)